# Stop while True loop with console input

Tags: python-2.7

I'm running python 2.7.12

Right now, I can tell it to start and it will begin looping... no problems. But I can't stop it. It gets caught in the loop and so I'm unable to enter the command to make it stop.

How can get out of the loop, so I can give commands?

```
def dothis():
    while True
        # Loop this infinitely until I tell it stop


while True:
    command = raw_input("Enter command:")

    if command = "start":
        dothis()
    if command = "stop":
        #Stop looping dothis()
```

Comment: You don't. It would never get to that part of the program to read your next command. You can break out of an infinite loop with `CTRL-C` and you can catch that (it's called `KeyboardInterrupt`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use threads like this:

```
import threading
import time

class DoThis(threading.Thread):
    def __init__( self ):
        threading.Thread.__init__( self )

        self.stop = False

    # run is where the dothis code will be
    def run( self ):
        while not self.stop:
            # Loop this infinitely until I tell it stop
            print( 'working...' )
            time.sleep( 1 )

a = None
while True:
    command = raw_input("Enter command:")

    if command == "start":
        a = DoThis()
        a.start()

    if command == "stop":
        a.stop = True
        a.join()
        a = None
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was after.

This is called multithreading, right?

Comment: Yes it is multithreading. Note that for any program is a little more complex you will want to look into the python thread-safe queues and locks.